# In the process of React / Redux development, what is the proper way to install bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, npm, webpack

I could do `npm install --save bootstrap`, but then it sits in `node_modules`.

One way is downloading the zip file and pulling needed files from it, but it doesn't feel you are using the standard ways of npm / webpack. So what is the standard way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install some dependencies to configure Bootstrap in react

First install the following `loaders` and `dependencies`

```
npm install react react-dom bootstrap babel-preset-react --save

npm install webpack css-loader style-loader file-loader url-loader babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

Now in your webpack you need to configure these loaders

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      { 
        test: /\.css$/, 
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader" 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.png$/, 
        loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.jpg$/, 
        loader: "file-loader" 
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, 
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, 
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
      },
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, 
        loader: 'file'
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, 
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

After this you need to import Bootstrap css in your entry file for example index.js like

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

Comment: do some of your steps get completed by these two lines: `sudo npm install -g create-react-app` and `create-react-app hello-world` ? Because if I do that and `npm install` and `npm start`, I already get an app that has `bundle.js`, so I suspect that webpack is already at work

Comment: You can check if that sets up the bootstrap loaders for you. I have'nt use create-react-app to initialize my project